# How can I get the IP Address of the connecting client in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I have two questions:

1) How can I get the IP address, and any other possible data about the client when it connects (see comment in code in the connect section)

2) Will this code safely allow multiple client connections at the same time?

```
var net = require('net');
var sys = require('sys');

var server = net.createServer(function (stream) {
  stream.setEncoding('utf8');

  stream.on('connect', function() {
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    console.log("WANT THE IP OF THE CONNECTOR HERE!!!!!!");
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  });

  // data recieve
  stream.on('data', function (data) {
    //stream.write(data);
    console.log("recv: [" + data + "]");
  });

  // end connection
  stream.on('end', function () {
    stream.end();
  });

});
server.listen(50505, 'localhost');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.2/api/net.html#stream.remoteAddress
2. Yes

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly.  What is the best way to find info like this?  There isn't a whole lot on google- albeit I was probably not entering the correct keywords.